# Apache mode_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, curl, apache2

I have 2 PHP scripts **test1.php** and **test2.php** which curl to the same remoter server where there are located. test1.php uses as URL **$url='http://myserver.com/api'** (remote server where scripts are located) and **test2.php** uses as URL `$url = 'http://localhost/api'`.  And also I have this **.htaccess** file in root folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On 
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
```

The response from **test1.php** is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 19 Sep 2014 20:56:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PrestaShop Webservice
```

And response from **test2.php** is:

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Moved
Date: Fri, 19 Sep 2014 20:57:49 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4
location: http://myshop.com/?url=products&display=%5Bid%5D&limit=5
```

Why it is so? And how can I fix **.htaccess** so that **test2.php** returns `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

Comment: I think this is a redirect inside PrestaShop and not a question of mod-rewrite. And there must be a cache or config where the old path is still active. Maybe there is a db table ps_shop_url? Have a look at this answer: http://www.newdavesite.com/view/19837463

Comment: @hellcode I want to access with localhost and myshop.com that is the problem